# A simple mod_rewrite rule in my .htaccess to redirect a friendly URL to the script

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

hi i'd like to rewrite http://www.domain.com/site_reg/index.php to http://www.domain.com/signup how would I do this. both for www.domain.com and domain.com?

EDIT: maybe i have it backwards... user types in http://www.domain.com/signup and http://www.domain.com/site_reg/index.php load the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for both www.domain.com and domain.com, assuming you have ServerName and ServerAlias set in your VirtualHost
Try:

```
<VirtualHost>
  ServerName domain.com
  ServerAlias www.domain.com

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^/site_reg/(.*) /signup/$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

You want to assign a 301 Redirect to tell search engines, browsers, etc. that the page has permanently moved.  If the move is not permanent, use the temporary status code: 307

Comment: hmm this redirects I just want to rewrite the link the user sees. site_reg/index.php would be still valid

Comment: In that case, you can drop the R flag from the RewriteRule directive.  Generally though, you'd want to keep the redirect in order to prevent having two URLs with the same content.

Comment: ThatBlairGuy is right. Rewriting the Url will look like duplicate content to search engines.  In some cases, this might not have a huge effect on search engine rankings (depending on the site and page).  Looks like this rewrite is to provide users with a user-friendly url.  Can the page afford to take a negative point of view from search engines?  If not, I would keep the R

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !FeedBurner
RewriteRule ^site_reg\/index\.php$ http://www.domain.com/signup [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your base `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^site_reg/index\.php$  http://www.domain.com/signup [R,L]
```

Comment: hmm that did not work, page can not be found. /site_reg/index.php loads fine though

Comment: Try doing `RewriteRule ^site_reg\/index\.php$ /signup [R,L]`